# Report on Lotus Notes Calender

Tags: java, c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We are using Lotus Notes 8.5. All meetings are scheduled through Lotus Notes.
I need to create a report on meetings data. Ex- Meeting held per month, Persons involved in meeting per month and hours spent by each employee in meetings per month.

Any pointer, how to do that ?
I am a java/C# programmer, Can i do it through C#/Java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use java to do this. But you need to install domino designer.

But this is not an easy task at all: The data is not centrally available anywhere, you need to collect it form the mail files of the users.
Therefor you need to cycle through all mail- files on your Domino server, collect all documents with form "Appointment", read the ApptUNID (as one appointment might be in the calendars of multiple users, if there were invitations involved), and start counting.

Repeating entries will be the most difficult thing to count, as there might be 2 - x documents for each repeating meeting (one head- document and one - x responses that contain the certain dates in a multivalue field).

You could start reading the [IBM Calendaring and Scheduling Schema](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc) just to get an idea about HOW complex this will get.

For an experienced IBM/Lotus Domino Developer this task would be at least one day of effort, without even knowing the structure of Domino Classes needed for this task, it will take ages and probably never succeed.

Because: After coding the solution you need to make sure, that the code runs with the right rights to access every single mailbox in your domain, that alone is not easy to achieve.

You really need to pay somebody to do this for you, or you will not finish this task this year (or probably never)